# Handling ajax errors with jsf.ajax.addOnError

Tags: ajax, jsf, error-handling

How does `jsf.ajax.addOnError` actually catch errors? 
I didn't find any information about it's mechanism. I only found that it is a error listener.

Comment: Why should an error listener catch errors? What exactly is it, the problem you're trying to solve, or the functional requirement you're trying to implement? This may generate better answers than asking a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you've found the statement that `jsf.ajax.addOnError` is an error-*listener*, that source is wrong. The `addOnError` function *adds* an error listener (ie, a function you define yourself and that gets called whenever the JSF framework encounters an error situation).

This is straight out of the [JSF-2.2 spec, 13.3.6.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr344/index.html):

> The jsf.ajax.addOnError function accepts a JavaScript function argument that will be
>   notified when errors occur during any Ajax request/response cycle. [P1-start-event] The implementation must ensure the JavaScript function that is registered must be called in accordance with the errors outlined in Section TABLE 14-5 “Errors”.[P1-end]

Thus, the "errors" table defines under which conditions your function will get called. Here they are:

- **httpError**: request status==null or request.status==undefined or request.status<200 or
       request.status >=300
- **serverError**: The Ajax response contains an “error” element.
- **malformedXML**: The Ajax response does not follow the proper format.
- **emptyResponse**: There was no Ajax response from the server.

JSF implementations basically fire a Ajax request and define internal handlers that get called by the browser when a response arrives. Then, they are required to inspect the response and if one the above conditions are met, they look up if you have registered any functions to be called and execute them if need be (they do a lot more, but that's the part in question here).

Comment: Based on OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936401/handling-ajax-errors), I believe he already knows this all.

Comment: @BalusC Well, that leaves the "adds an error listener" bit, ie pointing out the flawed premise of the question. There's no magic to explain here (for once!)

Comment: Yes, you answered it right. But I believe this doesn't help him solving his *actual* problem/requirement. I believe (s)he just asked the wrong question.

Comment: @BalusC Too bad I already expended my crystal ball allowance for today, then ;-) But yeah, I'm mainly hoping others find it useful and can save a trip to the spec document.